# InstantSearch in controlled mode with custom input element causes maximum update depth error

Tags: reactjs, algolia, instantsearch, react-instantsearch

With React InstantSearch, I am trying to a) use a custom search box and b) access the searchState (to determine if the user is searching or not).

This code causes `Maximum update depth exceeded` when something is typed in the searchbox. As shown in the comment, replacing `CustomSearch` with the default `Searchbox` fixes the problem.

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/algolia-react-forked-rwz22?file=/src/Search.js:253-886

```
const CustomSearch = () => {
  const Component = connectSearchBox(({ currentRefinement, refine }) => (
    <input
      type="search"
      style={{ border: "1px solid black" }}
      value={currentRefinement}
      onChange={(e) => refine(e.currentTarget.value)}
    />
  ));

  return <Component />;
};

function Search() {
  const [searchState, setSearchState] = React.useState({});

  return (
    <InstantSearch
      onSearchStateChange={setSearchState}
      searchState={searchState}
      searchClient={searchClient}
      indexName="movies"
    >
      <CustomSearch /> {/* <SearchBox/> works*/}
    </InstantSearch>
  );
}
```

[Here](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/widgets/search-box/react/#connector) are the `connectSearchBox` docs and[here](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/widgets/instantsearch/react/#widget-param-searchstate) is a small description about InstantSearch in controlled mode.